# Oracle SQL- Invalid Alter Table Option

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I have created the table below, The column with Payment status uses numbers (1&0) to display status of payments 1 if received and 0 if not. I filled up some of the lines with data. However I decided to use (Paid, Not Paid) instead of (1, 0). I tried to perform  `Alter table` and I got this error : ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option". I know this happens because the datatype in the table is set to numbers and already filled with numbers, but what is the easiest way to resolve this issue  ?

Thank you

```
Name                    Null?    Type         
----------------------- -------- ------------ 
OWNER_NAME                       VARCHAR2(20) 
APARTMENT_NUMBER                 VARCHAR2(4)  
TELEPHONE_NUMBER                 VARCHAR2(15) 
MONTH_YEAR                       VARCHAR2(6)  
FEE                              NUMBER       
PAYMENT_STATUS          NOT NULL NUMBER(1)    
MONEY_HANDED_TO_COMMITY          VARCHAR2(3)
```

Comment: Personally, I'd not "fix" it at all.  It's not broken.  If you want to show 'paid/not paid' then do translate it at query time, using a CASE statement.  If you change it to a longer string to hold text, there is a near 100% chance some invalid text will creep in.  At the very least, case-sensitivity will make future comparisons error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "easy" way.

- Create a new column
- update table and set new column's value (depending on those 0/1)
- drop the old column
- rename the new column to old name